# How to set background wallpaper change time Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I searched a lot over internet but there isn't any question like this. How would I set Background Wallpaper change every 15 minutes or so. So, the next wallpaper in series show up once the allotted time passes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a cmd windows and enter

control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper

This will bring up the windows 8 desktop wallpaper interface which allows you to set it to change.

Comment: what is the manual way to go there? Any idea in case I forget this command. Can you update you answer with a photo where to click once I am in Personalization?

Answer (score 0):

On the desktop, right-click.
From the context menu, click Personalize.

In the Personalization window, from the bottom of the right pane, click the Desktop Background option.

In the Desktop Background window, check the checkbox at the top-left corner of the image that you want to use as your desktop wallpaper.

you can select more than one image to rotate automaticcaly throughout the day. You can choose a time interval from the Change picture every drop-down list. You can also check the Shuffle checkbox to have Windows 10 change your chosen desktop images in a random order.

Once everything is configured, click Save changes, and close the Personalization window.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem is that you must set your wallpaper slideshow through the Personalization window (not by right clicking on them and selecting `Set as desktop background`). Otherwise the timing options doesn't displayed (although your wallpapers is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in an executable batch file for future use.  Create a text file with these lines:

```
@echo off

start cmd.exe /k control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper

taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe

exit
```

Save as `Bckgnd_timerCP.bat` or something similar.

Run that anytime you want to access your timer and pictures in the current wallpaper set.  It will automatically close the cmd window after it runs.

Hope that helps..

Comment: I think you can cut out the `cmd /k` part of the second line. Also, doesn't `/k` make Windows **k**eep the command prompt after it runs the other thing?

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the something similar and finally found a workable solution in a utility for Windows 7 named John's Background Switcher at https://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/

In order to get it to work on Windows 10, I had to set the Windows Background controls for desktop to solid color and no special options.  Then use the MORE settings in the background switcher program to manage all settings.  Works great With many additional functions such as an on screen calendar and others if you want them.  Several hotkey functions including Ctrl+Alt+N which switches to the next background in your selected folder.

That one Hotkey for switching the background was how I found it and this was the only method I could find to accomplish this. The VBS scripts to make that hotkey never seemed to work right.

None of the VBS Scripts I could find would work for some reason with most giving errors.  John's utility requires the addition of .Net 3.5